# RuntimeCompilation dependency issue with CSharp.Workspaces

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm writing an ASP .NET Core 3.1 App, and I want to enable Razor Runtime compilation

When I try

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
```

I get:

> NU1608: Detected package version outside of dependency constraint: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 2.8.0 requires Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp (= 2.8.0) but version Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp 3.3.0 was resolved.

It doesn't seem to matter which '-Version' I specify (tried several)

How do I resolve this dependency without descending even further into Dependency-hell?

Answer (score 8):

Turns out I needed to remove the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` reference as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50788326/802482

Who knew?

Answer (score 0):

If removing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design` is not an option, then you can explicitly add the 2 following nuget packages in the appropriate version (in this case 3.3.0):

- `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`
- `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces`